# Unity exporter plugin gives NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, plugins, unity-game-engine

I am trying to build an exporter plugin to export a 3d model to a given path with all the necessary files.

Exporter works really well but a **console error** occurs.

I want to get rid of that console error and I've tried a lot for days to find that error and fix it.

I cannot seem to find the error location to open as a code.

Please be kind enough to guide me to the right direction.

I'm a newbie to unity.

**Error message :**

```
    NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
UnityEditor.EditorGUIUtility.TempContent (System.String[] texts) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/editor/EditorGUIUtilityBindings.gen.cs:312)
UnityEditor.EditorGUI.Popup (Rect position, System.String label, Int32 selectedIndex, System.String[] displayedOptions, UnityEngine.GUIStyle style) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/editor/EditorGUIBindings.gen.cs:517)
UnityEditor.EditorGUILayout.Popup (System.String label, Int32 selectedIndex, System.String[] displayedOptions, UnityEngine.GUIStyle style, UnityEngine.GUILayoutOption[] options) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/EditorGUI.cs:5992)
UnityEditor.EditorGUILayout.Popup (System.String label, Int32 selectedIndex, System.String[] displayedOptions, UnityEngine.GUILayoutOption[] options) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/EditorGUI.cs:5985)
Expoter.OnGUI () (at Assets/LiveRoom/Scripts/Editor/Exporter.cs:45)
System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:222)
```

**I cannot find** :

`/Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/editor/EditorGUIUtilityBindings.gen.cs:312`

Comment: Double click on the error from unity editor and it should open up the line of code that is causing the error.

Comment: It does not open the location. I tried that.

Comment: You may want to zip the project and upload the link here. I will take a look at it.

Comment: I found the error. Exporter was going on a loop and some files were modifying while inside the loop. checking for that made the error go away